# Подвисает программа при использовании TWebbrowser

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, com, vcl, activex

В своём приложении вынужден использовать компонент TWebBrowser в связи с обязательным критерием наличие поддержки ActiveX для определённого сайта.

Суть проблемы сводится к тому что :

- (логика) удалённый сайт (не мой) который мы открываем в нашем экземпляре VCL компонента TWebBrowser , выполняет при нажатии на кнопку на странице ActiveX запрос к внешней программе (а именно CriptoPRO) которая начинает процедуру обмена с USB ключом и "подписывает документы"
- (проблема) процесс общения нашего TWebBrowser с внешним COM объектом сопровождается тормазами всего интерфейса программы , что на локальной машине не представляет проблемы в связи с непродолжительностью всей процедуры. Однако при использовании на виртуальной машине (что обязательно для меня) эти фризы столь велики что в Title формы наблюдается надпись (не отвечает) и в какой то момент удалённый сервер выполняет редирект (я так думаю по таймаут) хотя все действия вроди как призванные быть совершенными выполняются, то-есть сам факт общения с COM компонентом внешним работает но тормозит главную форму.

в связи с ограничениями VCL компонентов я не могу запустить работу TWebBrowser в отдельном потоке , от сюда и вопрос , как быть ?

PS. я думал о варианте отдельного приложения с одной лишь формой и TWebBrowser , запускать его и привязывать к своей форме через Parent , но это решение мне кажется очень кривым и не факт что оно решит проблему. Плюс сразу возникают вопросы по передаче команд этому внешнему приложению, а в частности URL навигации.

PS. обычный InternetExplorer на той же удалённой машине работает с внешним COM объектом нормально, возможно также долго но ни какого редиректа не происходит , интерфейс не виснет.

Comment: Попробуйте явно указать совместимость WB в реестре, чтобы не работать с эмуляцией IE7 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: это я сделал сразу же , т.к. сайт требует 11000  версию

Comment: Попробуй при помощи Process Monitor изучить кто-куда-что спрашивает у системы, какие ошибки, может какие-то вызовы аномально длинные.

Comment: Я предложу Вариант 1.запустите екземпляр браузера, и "затяните"  его к себе в окно через WINAPI `SetParent(ie_handle, Panel1.Handle)` Статус можно оценить по title и caption разных окон ие. Вариант 2. Попробуйте зайти в Component - Import ActiveX Control найти там Microsoft WebBrowser и импортировать свежую версию контрола браузера.